# I want to add sign in form of magento 2 checkout step

Tags: magento2, checkout, knockoutjs

[image]

I want to add sign in form of magento 2 to my checkout step and want to show sign in form when checking out how to call template of sign in form in my custom checkout step.

Comment: Have tried below article https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_step.html

Comment: i tried it i got the what i want as the picture above dipicts but i want a default magento login form and functionality in that checkout step.

Comment: sorry if this is known but... if the email is for an account on the checkout step magento requires they login or you could also use a module like https://github.com/bitExpert/magento2-force-login to restrict access to checkout pages... this would be less code/customisation to force a login for checkout

Comment: Try to add the `authentication` component to the children section of your new step.

Comment: Magento_Checkout/js/view/authentication shows a popup for signing in. which component shows the login text fields which as visible on url magento2/customer/account/login

Comment: which authentication component is showing the text fields as visible on magento login page.

Comment: Sohaib tanveer@:  impressed  to see the required function of  sign-in  on checkout page . if you have done .. please post module.

Comment: I have the same problem and I am trying to make a module for this but with no success https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/321663/how-to-move-customer-login-to-step-login-in-checkout/

Answer (score 2):

You can install this module https://github.com/graschik/magento-2-checkout-login-step. This module adds the login step on the checkout.
[image]
[image]