# Adding sign in as checkout step in the magento2

Tags: magento2

which js file is responsible for returning register **sign_in** template in magento2. As i want to add **sign_in** register to the checkout page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need an authentication component defined in the `checkout_index_index` layout:

```
<item name="authentication" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/authentication</item>
    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">authentication</item>
    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
        <!--Additional authentication fields-->
        <item name="errors" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/authentication-messages</item>
            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">messages</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

So js file is `Magento_Checkout/js/view/authentication` or `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/authentication.js` in file system and template for it is `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/authentication.html`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. what i want to do i have added a checkout step. It should show the magento2 defaule signin register form below  with functionality. can u help me with that.

Comment: @sohaibtanveer just add a new step https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_step.html

Comment: so i just have to put the above xml in my checkout_index_index is that true or i some other steps are also required.

Comment: @sohaibtanveer you should add own step first, then move that component. If you need some help with moving authentication component please, add new question. It will be better to write an answer in right place :)

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/297156/i-want-to-add-sign-in-form-of-magento-2-checkout-step

Comment: the mentioned link is the link of my old question it also contains the picture of my added step.