# How to move customer login to step login in checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, login, customer-login

I've added a new step to checkout based on https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_step.html and is working good.

What I want to do next is to move the authentication section from shipping step to the newly created step. I've called it "Login" step.

I've added to login step

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="authentication" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="login" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Custom_AdvancedCheckout/js/view/checkout-login-step</item>
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="authentication" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/authentication</item>
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <!--Additional authentication fields-->
                                                        <item name="errors" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/authentication-messages</item>
                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">messages</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
```

And to the template file

```
<li id="login" data-bind="fadeVisible: isVisible">
    <div class="step-title" data-bind="i18n: 'Login'" data-role="title"></div>
    <div id="checkout-step-title"
         class="step-content"
         data-role="content">

        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('authentication') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->

        <form data-bind="submit: navigateToNextStep" novalidate="novalidate">
            <div class="actions-toolbar">
                <div class="primary">
                    <button data-role="opc-continue" type="submit" class="button action continue primary">
                        <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Next'--><!-- /ko --></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</li>
```

And my js file

```
define(
    [
        'ko',
        'uiComponent',
        'underscore',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator'
    ],
    function (
        ko,
        Component,
        _,
        stepNavigator
    ) {
        'use strict';
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Custom_AdvancedCheckout/check-login'
            },

            //add here your logic to display step,
            isVisible: ko.observable(true),

            /**
             *
             * @returns {*}
             */
            initialize: function () {
                this._super();
                stepNavigator.registerStep(
                    'login',
                    null,
                    'Login',
                    this.isVisible,
                    _.bind(this.navigate, this),
                    9
                );

                return this;
            },

            navigate: function () {

                this.isVisible(true);
            },

            /**
             * @returns void
             */
            navigateToNextStep: function () {
                stepNavigator.next();
            }
        });
    }
);
```

And is not showing the form.

What I understand is that I have to add the authentication to this step and remove it from step shipping.

Can someone help me with a hint?

Answer (score 0):

You have two authentications now, remove the old one from checkout component

The layout: `checkout_index_index.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="authentication" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="login" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Custom_AdvancedCheckout/js/checkout-login-step</item>
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="authentication" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/authentication</item>
                                                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">authentication</item>
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <!--Additional authentication fields-->
                                                        <item name="errors" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/authentication-messages</item>
                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">messages</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

The template: `check-login.html`

```
<li id="login" data-bind="fadeVisible: isVisible">
    <div class="step-title" data-bind="i18n: 'Login'" data-role="title"></div>
    <div id="checkout-step-title"
         class="step-content"
         data-role="content">

        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('authentication') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->

        <form data-bind="submit: navigateToNextStep" novalidate="novalidate">
            <div class="actions-toolbar">
                <div class="primary">
                    <button data-role="opc-continue" type="submit" class="button action continue primary">
                        <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Next'--><!-- /ko --></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</li>
```

Step js file: `checkout-login-step.js`

```
define(
    [
        'ko',
        'uiComponent',
        'underscore',
        ‘Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator'
    ],
    function (
        ko,
        Component,
        _,
        stepNavigator
    ) {
        'use strict';
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: ‘ Custom_AdvancedCheckout/check-login'
            },

            //add here your logic to display step,
            isVisible: ko.observable(true),

            /**
             *
             * @returns {*}
             */
            initialize: function () {
                this._super();
                stepNavigator.registerStep(
                    'login',
                    null,
                    'Login',
                    this.isVisible,
                    _.bind(this.navigate, this),
                    9
                );

                return this;
            },

            navigate: function () {

                this.isVisible(true);
            },

            /**
             * @returns void
             */
            navigateToNextStep: function () {
                stepNavigator.next();
            }
        });
    }
);
```

This code add an auth popup trigger to your first step

Comment: I've tried but is not working. I've added more information to the initial post

Comment: Please see updated answer @andy1786

Comment: you have mention template and component from Magento_Checkout. Should not be from the plugin?

Comment: I’ve tested and copied from the Magento_Checkout from my theme. You need to replace with your module

Comment: Updated the answer